# Adding ecs fargate as target group with NLB with auto scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-nlb

I created an NLB and a fargate service.

Then i create a target group with "ip" of my ecs instance.

When i now add a fargate ip to my target group, it works, but how does the scaling work? Suppose ecs has to scale out, i will have to register another ip, but i want it to scale automatically.

Let us say one task is added. How does the network load balancer the new task ip without me manually adding it?

I do not get, how the link is between the nlb and the service of ecs. Does amazon does add targets implicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually registering the IP of your Fargate task with the target group, you are supposed to [configure the ECS service with knowledge of the load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/service-create-loadbalancer.html) you want to use. The ECS service will then automatically register every task that it creates as part of deployments and auto-scaling.

Comment: I just got my problem, i was using the "new" not really complete ecs experience

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Network Target Group, Attached the Fargate Service to Network Target group. Then Scale the Fargate based on the CPU/Memory Metrics.

CDK Code Example:

https://github.com/go-fireball/cdk-examples/blob/main/nlb-fargate/lib/stacks/nlb-fargate-stack.ts

```
    const networkTargetGroup = new cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.NetworkTargetGroup(this, `${config.environment}-${config.appName}-net-target-group`, {
        targetGroupName: `${config.environment}-${config.appName}-api`,
        port: 80,
        vpc: vpc,
        deregistrationDelay: Duration.seconds(0),
        connectionTermination: true,
        protocol: Protocol.TCP_UDP,
        targetType: TargetType.IP,
        healthCheck:{
            protocol: Protocol.HTTP,
            path: '/api/health',
        }
    }) 
     ...
     ...
    fargateService.attachToNetworkTargetGroup(networkTargetGroup);
     ...
     ...
    const applicationScalingTarget = fargateService.autoScaleTaskCount({
        minCapacity: 2,
        maxCapacity: 5,
    }); 
     applicationScalingTarget.scaleOnCpuUtilization (`${config.environment}-${config.appName}-api-scaling`,{
        targetUtilizationPercent: 50,
    })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).